# Switch classes without losing content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have `div#container`, which contains two divs `div.current-content` and `div.next-content`.
Both are filled with some content.
How I can switch class between next and current content without losing data? 
This is my original reason, but with this I lost everything in current-content.

```
changeContent = function (direction, toLoad) {

    if (direction == 'next') {
        container.append('<div class="next-content"></div>');
        toScroll = -contentWidth;
    } else {
        container.prepend('<div class="next-content"></div>').css('margin-left', -contentWidth);
        toScroll = 0;
    }

    container.css('width', contentWidth * 2);
    $('.current-content, .next-content').css('width', contentWidth);
    $('.next-content').load(toLoad, '', function () {

        // PSEUDO 3D                
        if (direction == 'next') {
            $('.next-content .content')
                .css('margin-left', contentWidth * 2)
                .animate({
                'margin-left': (contentWidth / 2) - 485
            }, {
                duration: speed,
                easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
                complete: function () {
                    $('.content').css('margin-left', 'auto');
                }
            });
            $('.current-content .content')
                .css('margin-left', (contentWidth / 2) - 485)
                .animate({
                'margin-left': -contentWidth
            }, {
                duration: speed,
                easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
            });
        } else {
            $('.next-content .content')
                .css('margin-left', -contentWidth * 2)
                .animate({
                'margin-left': (contentWidth / 2) - 485
            }, {
                duration: speed,
                easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
                complete: function () {
                    $('.content').css('margin-left', 'auto');
                }
            });

            $('.current-content .content')
                .css('margin-left', (contentWidth / 2) - 485)
                .animate({
                'margin-left': contentWidth * 2
            }, {
                duration: speed,
                easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
            });
        }
        container.animate({
            'margin-left': toScroll
        }, {
            duration: speed,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
            complete: function () {

                container.css({
                    'margin-left': 0,
                        'width': 'auto'
                });
                $('.current-content').remove();
                $('.next-content').addClass('current-content').removeClass('next-content');
                $('.current-content').css('width', '100%');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Posting a JSfiddle with your markup would help clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your `changeContent` function, you're calling:

```
$('.current-content').remove();
```

This removes element(s) with class `.current-content`.  Instead of this, you should hide it, either using css or javascript/jquery.

Using css:

- It would be best to assign a new class, for example `.prev-content`
- In your css file, add `display: none` or `visibility:hidden`

Using jQuery:

- I would still recommend assigning a new class as at css
- Select element and hide it using `$("{selector}").hide()`

And if you want to show it back, you can remove `.prev-content` class and add `.current-content` back, or just select it using jQuery and *un-hide* it, using `$("{selector}").show()`.

*`{selector}` stands for a selector that selects **only** the element you want to hide/show*